# React-native run-ios and xcode don't work

Tags: ios, react-native

I created an application on Windows that ran and even went up to the Play Store. This is a project for the git repository (bitbucket) and downloaded on the MacBook. The first time, the application ran normally on an iOS simulator, but it was not recognized as fonts that I used and as I'm new to working with Mac and iOS, I was unable to resolve it and ended up deleting the repository and downloading again. From that moment or application no longer runs on the macbook running reat-native run-ios.

I've already followed the guidelines [here](https://docs.rocketseat.dev/ambiente-react-native/errors/ios) but I still haven't got anything yet. Here is the error that appears:

```
The following build commands have failed:
Bundle PhaseScriptExecution \ React \ Native \ code \ and \ images /Users/macbook/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/XXXXXXXXX-chaxzhqkuszomdaeoykspwqsyqbb/Build/Intermediates.noindex/doctorfitStudents.buildXXDebug1XX.
```

I tried to run in Xcode and I get 3 errors:

```
ios /../ node_modules / react-native / scripts / .packager.env: permission denied

The / bin / sh command issued errors, but did not return a non-zero exit code to indicate failure

../.node_modules/react-native/scripts/react-native-xcode.sh: this file or directory does not exist

"react": "~16.9.0",  
"react-native": "~0.61.5",
```